# Crontab running a Node.js script

Tags: debian, cron, node.js, javascript

I have a script that runs at boot and every 1 min after.  This is a nodeJS script that executes a nightmare/cheerio to scrape a cricket site for scores.  This script itself runs until killed when processed in terminal.

```
xvfb-run -a node mvcc.js
```

Ideally I want this to run in a terminal when the pi boots but I am lost on that at the moment.
This is my cron

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/html/scoreboard/node/score/mscl-scrapper/ && xvfb-run -a node mvcc.js > /home/pi/mvcc.log 2>&1
```

How can I kill that previous process and then redo it when the new minute has passed?  Right now It starts a new process every time it runs and maxes out the CPU after about 10 min.

Comment: The real solution is to code the script so that it terminates when a certain condition is reached, such as so many seconds have passed. If that is not possible, wrap it in a shell script that writes the PID in a file and kills that PID each time it starts. Put the shell script in cron instead of mvcc.js.

Comment: Jobs run through `cron`, or `at`, or `batch`, aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`). 
  
One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
 Read `man 5 crontab`.
  
Look at the results of  `echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.
  
Since the `comm

Comment: Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.